# NoMethodError - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I'm working through Code4Startup airbnb course (https://code4startup.com/projects/build-airbnb-with-ruby-on-rails-level-1) but I'm trying to adapt it for my own idea - an airbnb for education courses for my local colleges. I'm new to ruby and stackoverflow, I've tried searching for the solution for ages but my issue is that I don't know how to correctly describe it, so please explain it like I'm 5!

**The error I'm receiving:**

The error seems to be suggesting that my course model isn't being built correctly or that it is reverting back to the Listing model somehow (perhaps because my course_params aren't correct?)

```
NoMethodError in Courses#new
Showing /Users/Jack_R/code/rails/planet_study/app/views/courses/new.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined method `type' for #<Listing:0x007fc25da72ea8>
Extracted source (around line #22):
20
21
22

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Course Type</label>
              <%= f.select :type, [["English Language", "English Language"], ["Culture", "Culture"], ["Sports", "Sports"], ["Tech/Science", "Tech/Science"], ["Adventure", "Adventure"], ["Mixture", "Mixture"]],
                            id: "type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**My Models**

I have a User model, a Listing model and a Course model (User>Listing>Course):

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :listings
    has_many :courses, :through => :listings
  end
```

Listing model:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :courses
end
```

Course model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

**Courses Controller**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_course, except: [:index, :new, :create]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @courses = current_user.listings.courses
  end

  def new
    @course = current_user.listings.build
  end

  def create
    @course = listings.build(course_params)
    if @course.save
      redirect_to listing_course_path(@course), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
    end
  end

  def show

  def listing
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
  end

  def amenities
  end

  def location
  end

  def update
    if @course.update(course_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private

  def set_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  def room_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name, :type, :summary, :address, :places, :start_date, :finish_date, :price)
  end

end
end
```

**Course new.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Create your course listing
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="devise-container">

      <%= form_for @course do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          </div>

          <div class="col_md_4 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Course Type</label>
              <%= f.select :type, [["English Language", "English Language"], ["Culture", "Culture"], ["Sports", "Sports"], ["Tech/Science", "Tech/Science"], ["Adventure", "Adventure"], ["Mixture", "Mixture"]],
                            id: "type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col_md_4 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Places</label>
              <%= f.select :places, [["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3], ["4", 4], ["5", 5], ["6", 6], ["7", 7]],
                            id: "places", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div><%= f.submit "Create My Course", class: "btn btn-primary-green" %></div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're dealing with a reserved word, can you check the attribute type exists for your Course model?

Comment: Ah ok thank you @Sebastián Palma. I'm sorry I don't know how to do that, is there a way in irb?

Comment: Check in your `db/schema.rb` file.

Comment: It's in there @SebastiánPalma:
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "type"

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a reserved word in Rails. You can create a model with a `type` attribute, but you can't perform actions on this model until you rename the type attribute.

If you try to create a new record, through the rails console, you'll see a message like:

```
$ rails console
[1] pry(main)> Course.new(name: 'first', type: 'some type')
```

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism
>   failed to locate the subclass: 'some type'. This error is raised because
>   the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of
>   inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be
>   used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
>   Course.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
>   from
>   /Users/***/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:196:in
>   `rescue in find_sti_class'

As the message says, you must rename the type attribute to be able to work with it, to do it just run a migration to change this name and edit the file created, like:

```
$ rails generate migration rename_type_to_type_of
```

In the generated file use the `rename_colum` method, and specify first the model, then the old attribute name, and then the new one, like:

```
class RenameTypeToTypeOf < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_column :courses, :type, :type_of
  end
end
```

After that you can run `rails db:migrate`. Note `type_of` is just a poor suggestion of mine, you can adapt it as you want.

Comment: I had this exact problem and renamed `type` to `kind`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma unfortunately that hasn't solved it completely, i renamed the 'type' attribute to 'curriculum_type' and now I get the error:    undefined method `curriculum_type' for #<Listing:0x007fac167b94f8>
seems like it's not recognising that I'm trying to set the 'curriculum_type' for Course instead of Listing

Comment: Maybe I should write this as a separate question without the rails reserved word red herring?

Comment: Did you run `rails db:migrate`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes

Comment: I'm going to start a new question and close this one down as it is now misleading. Thanks for your help

Comment: Renaming the attribute solves the problem in this question, further problems must be covered in a new one.